# Заполнение comboBox из БД SQLite в PyQt

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt6

Пытаюсь заполнить `comboBox` из БД SQLite, но ничего не подтягивается.

Мой код

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
import sqlite3
from test_rt_sql import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.model = QSqlTableModel()
    self.model.setTable('user')
    self.model.select()
    self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)
    self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_val)

    self.show()

def comboBox_val(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/sqlite/test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
    rows = c.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(row)

    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Попробовал в `addItems` вернуть ему список, получил ошибку

```
    self.ui.comboBox.addItems(self.comboBox_val)
TypeError: addItems(self, texts: Iterable[Optional[str]]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'method'
```

Как я понимаю, ему не нравится в аргументе `addItems` , что там не конкретно на данные ссылаемся, а на метод.

Код где возвращал список:

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
import sqlite3
from test_rt_sql import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('user')
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(self.comboBox_val)

        self.show()

    def comboBox_val(self):
        global data1
        conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/sqlite/test.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
        data1 = []

        for row in c.fetchall():
            data1.append(str(row))

        return data1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec()
```

БД точно подключается, и отдаться данные. Проверил это так.

```
import sqlite3

def comboBox_val():
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/sqlite/test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

comboBox_val()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю код оформления не так важен, если необходимо могу и его опубликовать.

Comment: у вас напутано и модель и заполнение вручную.

Comment: Я вроде понимаю о чем вы, но все же ни как не пойму как мне извлечь данные из таблицы для заполнения.  Уже просмотрел достаточно много информации, но для PyQt не нашел для себя исчерпывающего ответа.

Comment: Вроде setQuery ещё нужно

Comment: Послезавтра буду такой код писать)

Comment: Да , в сторону setQuery и нужно было копать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я изначально свернул не туда, по покопав в сторону, подсказанную @eri, вопрос решил.

Подключаемся к базе `create_connection` , а дальше уже `QSqlTableModel` , сам запрос указал в `setQuery`

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase
from test_rt_sql import Ui_MainWindow

def create_connection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/sqlite/test.db")
    return True

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        create_connection()

        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('user')
        self.model.setQuery('SELECT name FROM user')
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Селект не нужно